# How to access services registered on consul directly from browser

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, consul

I have spring boot service add-service running on my machine on port 9090. This service is registered with consul which is running on the same machine. I can see the service in consul UI.  How can access this service directly from browser without ip :port where service is running?

Note: In some tutorials it is said that consul services can be accessed as http://add-service.service.consul but that is not working.